# Store subscribe vs. reactive statements

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In Svelte, are those 2 statements equivalent?

```
import { connected } from '$stores'

connected.subscribe((val) => {
  if(val) console.log("connected")
})

$: if($val) console.log("connected")
```

For a store variable, what are the differences between a store subscribe and a reactive statement conditioned on its value ?

Comment: A store can be shared. Shared state vs local component state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you explicitly use `subscribe` you should also unsubscribe. If you use `$store`, Svelte does everything automatically.

Also, the handler for store changes gets called immediately while reactive statements are triggered at most once per event loop if the component was marked as dirty.

In a component you usually should *not* subscribe to stores manually.